# Как вывести из БД на сайт русские буквы

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу тип товара который выложил пользователь с таблицы table_products. В таблице table_products есть столбец name(там все категории на английском языке) Как можно сделать так чтобы я вытаскивал с бд на английском языке, а на сайте показывалось на русском?
 К стате у меня есть таблица другая category где есть эти категории на русском name_ru

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE products_id='$id'",$connect);
```

вывожу

```
<p id="nav-info"><a href="view_things.php">Вещи</a>/<span>'.$row1["name"].'</span></p>
```

вот как показывает на сайте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну а что мешает вывести $row1['name_ru']

Comment: Не получается. name_ru в другой таблице(category), а это table_products товар предложенный пользователем

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать дополнительные столбцы в БД:

- name_ru
- name_en

И сделать условие - если сессия/куки языка - ru, будет браться из `$row1['name_ru']`.

А если Вам именно из другой таблицы нужно взять `name_ru/eng`, тогда Вы можете использовать INNER JOIN:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_products as p INNER JOIN category as c ON p.category_id = c.id WHERE p.id=$id
```

И после выборки Вы так же сможете отдавать нужные поля в зависимости от языка сайта.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_products as p INNER JOIN category as c ON p.category_id = c.id WHERE p.id=$id не отображает вообще ни чего:(

Comment: @Евгений, А у Вас есть столбец category_id в table_products?

И можно посмотреть на таблицы?

Comment: Нет нету. А как вам показать?

Comment: Тогда понятно почему код не работает. 
Мой код,подразумевает то,что у Вас будет в table_products category_id - который будет вести на id таблицы category. А в category уже должны быть столбцы с разными языками.

Следовательно,если у Вас в продуктах есть category_id = 1, это означает,что у Вас должна быть запись в category с id =1.

Comment: у меня есть category с родительскими и дочерними списками рус и англ, но когда пользователь предлагает товар то в бд идет англ значение в table_products

Comment: как я понимаю,в продукты вообще не должно идти английское значение. в бд должен иди category_id, что бы с помощью INNER JOIN можно было взять его,и все остальные,которые Вы переведете к тому времени как будете утверждать продукт.

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести таблицу ассоциаций (локалей) со столбцами `en_category_id` и `ru_category_id`. Количество столбцов зависит от количества языков локализации.